# I am getting the attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild' error in my tower defense game

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a tower defense game and just got `attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'` error in my health script. The tower is looking at the enemy, playing the animations, it just does not show the updated health of the zombies. The supposed code in question is     `local humanoid = model:WaitForChild("Humanoid")` Does anybody know how to make it show updated health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model` is nil. Make sure you set it properly.

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding so I am confused. The zombies are models and stay models when they enter the map, I also don't know where I would change the code to make sure the model is in the map.

Comment: Without any additional code I can not really help you with that. I can only tell you why the error happens. Start with the definition of `model`, how do you set it, and does this setting work?